# Message formatting, send buttons via Slack API with PHP

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I'm using webhooks to send messages via Slack API

I need to send a button with a link to a report

I did it with Python successfully

But with PHP i'm having trouble with the arrays of actions in the attachments

## code 1

```
$data = array(
        "text" => $message
    );

    $actions =
        [
            'type' => "button",
            'text' => "Report1",
            'url' => "https://url.report1"
        ];

    $data += [
        "attachments" =>
            [
                "fallback" => "More details...", //I only get the message and this text in the slack
                'actions' => [$actions] // or array($actions) 

            ]
    ];

    $payload = json_encode($data);
```

`print_r($data)` output:

```
Array
(
    [text] => teste
    [attachments] => Array
        (
            [fallback] => More details... 
            [actions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => button
                            [text] => Report1
                            [url] => https://url.report1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The paylod is shown, but the button doesn't

## code 2

```
$data = array(
        "text" => $message
    );

    $actions =
        [
            'type' => "button",
            'text' => "Report1",
            'url' => "https://url.report1"
        ];

    $data += [
        "attachments" =>
            [
                "fallback" => "More details...",
                'actions' => $actions

            ]
    ];

    $payload = json_encode($data);
```

`print_r($data)` output:

```
Array
(
    [text] => teste
    [attachments] => Array
        (
            [fallback] => More details...
            [actions] => Array
                (
                    [type] => button
                    [text] => Report1
                    [url] => https://url.report1
                )

        )

)
```

Neither payload or button are showed

Here's the documentation example, it's very easy to send this with [python](https://github.com/guilhermebferreira/slack_webhooks/blob/master/webhook-message_with_buttons.ipynb)

```
{
    "text": "<@W1A2BC3DD> approved your travel request. Book any airline you like by continuing below.",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Book your flights at https://flights.example.com/book/r123456",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": "Book flights ",
                    "url": "https://flights.example.com/book/r123456"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can create this kind of structure in PHP?

Comment: here the documentation about it https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#link_buttons

Comment: the work around was write the json "manually"

Comment: I think your attachments are not correct. it must be an array of arrays. You only have a simple array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your "code 1" with the correction. Your attachments property needs to be an array of attachment arrays. You only had a simple array.

```
$message = "Hello Stackoverflow";

$data = array(
        "text" => $message
    );

    $actions =
        [
            'type' => "button",
            'text' => "Report1",
            'url' => "https://url.report1"
        ];

    $data += [
        "attachments" =>
            [
                [
                    "fallback" => "More details...", //I only get the message and this text in the slack
                    'actions' => [$actions] // or array($actions) 

                ]
            ]
    ];

    $payload = json_encode($data);

    print_r($payload);
```

The resulting payload works in the [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Hello%20Stackoverflow%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22More%20details...%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Report1%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Furl.report1%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: @Guilherme if this answer solved your question (which I believe it did) please consider marking it as solution. Ty

Comment: Great! I was so focused on 'actions' that I did not realize that 'attachments' was also an array of arrays